# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'med_portal.Custparent' doesn't exist")

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

### I am using a ManyToMany Through model accross two databases.

```
'default': {},
    'portaldb': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'med_portal',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        },
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '***.***.**.*',
        'PORT': '****',
    },
    'smgpr': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'supplies',
        'OPTIONS': {
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"
        },
        'USER': '****',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '***.***.
    **.*',
        'PORT': '****',
    },
```

### Router file1(LocalRouter.py):

```
#LocalRouter.py
class DBLocalRouter(object):


    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):

        app_list = ('auth', 'admin', 'contenttypes', 'sessions', 'messages', 'staticfiles', 'Test', 'Admin', 'Charges', 'Products', 'Patients', 'Relationships', 'apis', 'corsheaders', 'djoser', 'django_filters', 'users', 'rest_framework', 'debug_toolbar')

        if model._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return 'smgpr'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):

        app_list = ('auth', 'admin', 'contenttypes', 'sessions', 'messages', 'staticfiles', 'Test', 'Admin', 'Charges', 'Products', 'Patients', 'Relationships', 'apis', 'corsheaders', 'djoser', 'django_filters', 'users', 'rest_framework', 'debug_toolbar')
        if model._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return 'smgpr'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):

        app_list = ('auth', 'admin', 'contenttypes', 'sessions', 'messages', 'staticfiles', 'Test', 'Admin', 'Charges', 'Products', 'Patients', 'Relationships', 'apis', 'corsheaders', 'djoser', 'django_filters', 'users', 'rest_framework', 'debug_toolbar')
        if obj1._meta.app_label in app_list and obj2._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):

        app_list = ('auth', 'admin', 'contenttypes', 'sessions', 'messages', 'staticfiles', 'Test', 'Admin', 'Charges', 'Products', 'Patients', 'Relationships', 'apis', 'corsheaders', 'djoser', 'django_filters', 'users', 'rest_framework', 'debug_toolbar')

        if app_label in app_list:
            return db == 'smgpr'
        return None
```

### Router file2(GlobalRouter.py):

```
#GlobalRouter.py
class DBGlobalRouter(object):
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        """
        Attempts to read portal models go to portal.
        """
        app_list = ('portal', 'Test',)

        if model._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return 'portaldb'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        app_list = ('portal', 'Test',)
        if model._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return 'portaldb'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        app_list = ('portal', 'Test',)
        if obj1._meta.app_label in app_list and obj2._meta.app_label in app_list:
            return True
        return True

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model=None, **hints):        
        app_list = ('portal', 'Test',)

        if app_label in app_list:
            return db == 'portaldb'
        return None
```

### The models for app1:

```
    class User(AbstractBaseUser):
        username            = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        email               = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
        full_name           = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        custparent          = models.ManyToManyField('portal.Custparent', related_name='facility', through='Relation')
        active              = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        staff               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        admin               = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        jwt_secret          = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4)
        created_at          = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Relation(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        custparent = models.ForeignKey('portal.Custparent', related_name='profile', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

        class Meta:
            db_table= 'relation'
            unique_together = ('user', 'custparent')
```

### The models for app2:

```
    pbd_name = settings.DATABASES['portaldb']['NAME']


    class Custparent(models.Model):
        custparent_id = models.BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        comm_queue = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
        email = models.CharField(db_column='EMail', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        invoice_email = models.CharField(db_column='Invoice_EMail', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        portal_id = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
        sentupdate = models.DateTimeField(db_column='SentUpdate', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        webaddress = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        webext = models.CharField(max_length=3, blank=True, null=True)
        passcode = models.CharField(db_column='PassCode', max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        autoapprove = models.IntegerField(db_column='AutoApprove', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        testaccount = models.IntegerField(db_column='TestAccount', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        privateemail = models.IntegerField(db_column='PrivateEmail', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        forcemanponum = models.IntegerField(db_column='ForceManPONum', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        procuretopay = models.IntegerField(db_column='ProcureToPay', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        medassets_member = models.IntegerField(db_column='MedAssets_Member', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        medassets_facnum = models.IntegerField(db_column='MedAssets_FacNum', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        hideglorder = models.IntegerField(db_column='HideGLOrder', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        searchall = models.IntegerField(db_column='SearchAll', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        accountlabel = models.CharField(db_column='AccountLabel', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        inhouselabel = models.CharField(db_column='InHouseLabel', max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        privatelabellogo = models.CharField(db_column='PrivateLabelLogo', max_length=120, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        hin = models.CharField(db_column='HIN', max_length=9, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        gln = models.CharField(db_column='GLN', max_length=13, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        shiptoattn = models.CharField(db_column='ShiptoAttn', max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        shiptoaddress = models.CharField(db_column='ShiptoAddress', max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        shiptocity = models.CharField(db_column='ShiptoCity', max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        shiptostateprov = models.CharField(db_column='ShiptoStateProv', max_length=24, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        shiptopostalcode = models.CharField(db_column='ShiptoPostalCode', max_length=24, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        shiptophone = models.CharField(db_column='ShiptoPhone', max_length=24, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        shiptofax = models.CharField(db_column='ShiptoFax', max_length=24, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        multivendor = models.IntegerField(db_column='MultiVendor', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        lockformulary = models.IntegerField(db_column='LockFormulary', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        active = models.IntegerField(db_column='Active', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        autoadded = models.IntegerField(db_column='AutoAdded', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        allowpatientedit = models.IntegerField(db_column='AllowPatientEdit', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
        displaymaxonorders = models.IntegerField(db_column='DisplayMaxOnOrders', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

        class Meta:
            managed = False
            # db_table = 'custparent'
            db_table = '`%s`.`custparent`' % pbd_name

        def __str__(self):
            return f'{str(self.custparent_id)} - {self.name}'
```

When creating an object using the Relation table in the admin, every thing works fine. However whenever I am trying to the view the User objects in the browsable api with DjangoRestFramework. I get this error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'med_portal.relation' doesn't exist")

### Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 117, in _get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, callback, callback_args, callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/middleware.py", line 85, in process_view
    response = panel.process_view(request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/profiling.py", line 160, in process_view
    return self.profiler.runcall(view_func, *args, **view_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/cProfile.py", line 109, in runcall
    return func(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/viewsets.py", line 116, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 495, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 455, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 492, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 45, in list
    return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 765, in data
    ret = super(ListSerializer, self).data
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 262, in data
    self._data = self.to_representation(self.instance)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 683, in to_representation
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 683, in <listcomp>
    self.child.to_representation(item) for item in iterable
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/serializers.py", line 527, in to_representation
    ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 542, in to_representation
    for value in iterable
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 268, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1186, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1065, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 186, in execute
    return self._record(self.cursor.execute, sql, params)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/debug_toolbar/panels/sql/tracking.py", line 124, in _record
    return method(sql, params)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 71, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 250, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 50, in defaulterrorhandler
    raise errorvalue
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 247, in execute
    res = self._query(query)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 411, in _query
    rowcount = self._do_query(q)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 374, in _do_query
    db.query(q)
  File "/home/iclark/.local/share/virtualenvs/backend-2BnCgv4_/lib/python3.6/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 277, in query
    _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'med_portal.relation' doesn't exist")
```

## Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have these oversimplified structures:

**app1.models**

```
from django.db import models

class A(models.Model):
    z = models.TextField()
```

**app2.models**

```
from django.db import models

class B(models.Model):
    aref = models.ForeignKey(to='app1.A', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**app1.app1_router**

```
class MyAppRouter:
    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in ('app1', 'test'):
            return 'app1_db'
        return 'default'

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in ('app1', 'test'):
            return 'app1_db'
        return None

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label in ('app1', 'test') or obj2._meta.app_label in ('app1', 'test'):
            return True

        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in ('app1', 'test'):
            return db == 'app1_db'
        return None
```

with these settings for the databases:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },

    'app1_db': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app1.sqlite3'),
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ["app1.app1_router.MyAppRouter",]
```

Now obviously we have two databases

- the main database: ***default***
- the app1 database: ***app1_db***

And we obviously have a `aref = ForeignKey` from `app2.B` (which lives in the `default` database) to `app1.A` (which lives in the `app1_db` database).

We will obviously migrate the database as:

```
./manage.py migrate
./manage.py migrate --database=app1_db
```

to cover both databases.

Now let's assume we want to create two objects and link them together for these models:

```
a1 = A.objects.create()
b1 = B.objects.create(aref=a1)
```

what will happen is that the `a1` instance will be easily created since our `MyRouter` router will handle the database write, and will direct the `SQL INSERT` to the `app1_db` as desired, but the problem comes when we're trying to write the `B` instance, especially when we're trying to link to a `app1_a` model, which doesn't exist in the `default` database (happening because of the `aref=a1`).

What I'm guessing happens when you're trying to access it via `rest_framework` is basically the same thing.

The thing is Django operates on a single database at a time and as far as I'm concerned there are two options:

- either use a single database (spares you of the pain of doing customisation and the question here is, why would you need multiple databases in the first place?)
- migrate the table in both databases and synchronize across the two databases on save (a lot of customisation -> depends on your architecture decision). Example for solving the issue with the foreign key makes use of some custom `ForeignKey` implementation [like in this article](https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/6839e4), with [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/gcko/de1383080e9f8fb7d208)

Comment: Thanks for responding, this detailed answer is just what I needed.

Comment: Would I run into any race conditions?

Comment: @DewonClark theoretically no since the operations happen sequentially and switched. But I guess it all depends to the customization code you are using in syncing multiple databases.

Comment: @DewonClark But what are your concerns on this?

Comment: This will be used by 1000 of workers at multiple different locations, and I was wondering would this effect the speed and or efficiency?

Comment: @DewonClark hmm well it depends what the workers are doing and how much data they are exchanging with the database. If you plan in storing let's say thousands or tens of thousands of data in the database then the querying will be slowed down regardless of the number of the workers. Or if these workers are accessing the database via a web API then it boils down to the server hardware capabilities and load balancing as well as the serialization/deserialization algorithm.

Comment: It would be via web API

Comment: @DewonClark the routing itself will not contribute to the slow down as long at is kept fairly simple. The more synchronization you add to it the slower it will become as well, but that also boils down to the actual customisation as I was saying earlier

Comment: Would it be overkill to include a syncdb function in my routers.py file?

Comment: @DewonClark I'm not sure I follow what you are asking.

Comment: Nevermind, I was reading the wrong version of the django docs.

Comment: Would I still need to set the db_constraint=False on the foreign key?

Comment: @DewonClark in the case of using a `SpanningForeignKey` ?

Comment: Yes for migration purposes?

Comment: theoretically it shouldn't be necessary since the code from that article overwrites the validation, so basically you shouldn't get any validation error during migration, or did you try it and it did throw some sort of error?

Comment: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'med` FOREIGN KEY (`custparent_id`) REFERENCES `med_portal`.`custpare' at line 1")